# MySql 'INTO OUTFILE ' from MySql commandline

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my(dummy) query, which runs fine on the machine where mysql-server is hosted BUT fails on  another machine, when I connect using the same user. (root)

```
SELECT *
FROM data
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dump.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Error I get on mysql>  prompt :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'foobar.com' (using password: YES)
```

I have granted "ALL PRIVILEGES"  to 'root'@'%'

Am I missing something ?

Adding some more data :

1. Following query works fine , which means the user is connected to right database and has read permission at the least.

   SELECT *
   FROM data limit 5;
2. I did do a server side FLUSH privileges;
   How much time I am supposed to wait ?  Any ballpark number ? I doubt it would be longer than few minutes.

Comment: Do you need to call 'flush privileges'?

Comment: does your output file already exist? I don't think it will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created an account 'root'@'foobar.com' on the server. You can check it like this:

```
use information_schema;
select user, host from user;

mysql> select user, host from user;
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | ::1       |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You might also have an issue mixing wild card users (%) and users with explicit host, if both match mysql should deny access.

Comment: 1. mysql doesn't seem to have 'user' table under information_schema.

2. Also I had given permission using GRANT ALL ... 'root'@'%' which should have included all the permissions.

3. I am able to do  a 'select * from tbl'  query, I am having problem only in the FILE output operation related query.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the error number `ERROR 1045 (28000)` following are the possible reasons why you are getting this error. Assuming `user` here is mysql user but not Linux/Windows user of the machine

1. You are trying to connect to a different TCP/IP port from which the server is listening. Use --port option to correct this.
2. Check the server configuration whether it is allowing network connection if you are trying to connect from a remote machine. Check `--skip-networking` option in configuration file
3. If `bind-address=127.0.0.1` then mysql server will listen only the local connections and it will not listen to remote connections
4. May be a **firewall is blocking** your connection. To verify this `Telnet` or `ssh` to the server from a remote machine. As shown below.

   `$telnet 192.168.1.1 3306`
5. In the above query you are trying to **write a csv file** from the query. Make sure that you have the appropriate user permissions to write the file.
6. As you said you have already did `FLUSH PREVILEGES`. Try to use the `mysqladmin flush-previleges` from the root prompt for you machine.

I have given some ideas to debug your problem. Probably above solutions will help you in solving your problem. Cheers

Comment: when instead of file operation I choose to make just a select * from tbl limit 5; ,  works just fine, which means  there is no connectivity or read permission issue.
Also the user executing the query has permission to read/write in /tmp folder. (not having that permission would have given different error anyways.)